# Solve a Formula Containing Round Function

Tags: math, formula

I'm calculating amount of payments in an e-commerce application based on the following formula (Note 1: this is just some pseudo-code, Note 2: we have several taxes to apply and each one is rounded to 2 decimal digits):

```
eachPayment = (price + sum(round(price * taxRate1, 2) + round(price * taxRate2, 2) + ...) - downPayment) / numberOfPayments
```

Now, at some point I want to calculate `price`, based on other values (I have eachPayment, taxRate, downPayment and numberOfPayments). How can I do that, considering the presence of `round` which depends on `price`?

This should be done in Javascript, but any general clue or samples in other programming languages would be fine.

Comment: What is this round method? The standard JavaScript `round(x)` method only accepts one parameter, but you are passing in two. Is this perhaps meant to be `sum(round(price * taxRate), 2)` ?

Comment: Which rounding mode?

Comment: What then would the sum method do? It is being given just a single parameter.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is just pseudo-code. Assume that round is a custom function I've written. And what sum does should be obvious.

Comment: I edited the formula to clarify sum, and remove javascript tag.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of unknowns about your function. The built in JavaScript `round(x)` method only takes one parameter, but yours is given two. You are also using an unknown `sum(x)` method that only takes one parameter, which is a bit nonsensical, given what sum means.

Disregarding that, the closest one can get is:

```
price = (downPayment + (eachPayment * numberOfPayments)) / (1 + taxRate1 + taxRate2 + ...);
```

It is impossible to know the amount that was rounded off.

Comment: Edited the question. round() is a custom function and there are multiple taxRates.

Comment: Edited my answer. It is more or less the same. Assuming that your custom `round` function rounds off data, it is still impossible to account for that.